# How to auto register spring beans using reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-bean

My application consists of 2 modules, I have some classes under `module-B`, what I want is to dynamically load `jar` of `module-B`in `module-A` and register those classes as beans in `context` of `module-A`.

I don't have any `context` under `module-B`, so loading context of `module-B` in my parent `module-A` is not an option for me.

What I have tried so far:

[JCL](https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL/) , but I am unable to figure out how should I register those beans.

What am I missing ? Is there a better way to do it without creating contexts in child module and loading them in parent.

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to do this by hand instead of using component scanning and/or autoconfiguration?

Comment: I am not using `component-scan` since those classes are not on my module-A `classpath`, I need to somehow dynamically load them to `classpath` or somehow `component-scan` `module-B` `classpath`.

Comment: Are the classes in module A not on module B's classpath only at compile time or also not on the classpath at runtime?

Comment: `Module-A` is parent module, and it requires classes from `module-B`, now these classes are neither there at compilie time nor on runtime unless I load them dynamically on runtime.

Comment: They're not there at runtime either, theb. You really need to reorganize your modules to accurately reflect your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context for configuring your module-A stuff, then you can load your module-B jar, and add your beans with the following code

```
       DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

       public void addComponent(Object component) {
                if (component instanceof Class) {
                    Class clazz = (Class) component;
                    GenericBeanDefinition beanDef = new GenericBeanDefinition();
                    beanDef.setBeanClass(clazz);
                    beanDef.setAutowireCandidate(true);
                    beanDef.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_CONSTRUCTOR);
                    String beanName = clazz.getName();
                    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDef);
                } else {
                    beanFactory.registerSingleton(component.getClass().getName(), component);
                }
            }
```